# Favicon not being displayed in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, favicon

I have a document like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>mac</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon"  href="http://194.88.245.110/favicon.ico" 
        type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
    <span class="generated">18.12.2013 01:01:43</span>
    <p class="nobody">Nikogo nie wykryto.</p>
</body>
```

Here's my favicon, base64-encoded (I put the binary version on the server, of course):

```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```

Firefox doesn't seem to recognize this favicon - it's Windows 16x16 .ico format, PNG-compressed. It doesn't display it on a tab nor in bookmarks and in "page details" it says that its size is 0x0. What could be the reason?

Comment: Using Data URIs in the favicon is possible but remember browsers don't cache Data URIs... So what your doing is actually slowing the process down > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199902/isnt-it-silly-that-a-tiny-favicon-requires-yet-another-http-request-how-to-mak is a work around but to be honest even a JavaScript is a server side request which defealts the objective of even using a data URI to start off with. Best just to serve the favicon tbh.

Comment: I didn't use Data URI in the original document, I used it here to display the file in a plaintext form.

Comment: Sorry, that's what happens when I skim questions :P

Answer (score 3):

I decoded that image and opened it with Firefox.  Firefox was able to read it just fine.

I visited your website (found through reverse image search for the icon) and confirmed that in Firefox, the icon does not show up in the tab.

I looked at your source code.  You should add the following code into the head of your website.  It will trigger browsers other than Internet Explorer to fetch the favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: What you probably looked at is `/`, while the document is located at `/mac2/`, here: http://194.88.245.110/mac2/ - as you can see, the `rel` is already there.

Comment: The favicon shows up in the tab there for me.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Just curious how you did a "reverse image search"? If I do, what I think is, a reverse image search in Google I get 5 other sites, not the site in question. (But the IP address would seem to already be given in the question...?)

Comment: Yes, I think I got the wrong site when I dragged the image into Google image search.

Comment: You can take a look at browser screenshots to see if your favicon appears or not, as with [here](http://browsershots.org) (check for Firefox versions) - seems OK to me too.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Firefox too. 
On my website the favicon on `http://example.com` worked 
fine but not on `http://www.example.com`.

I fixed it by hardcoding the favicon.

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='http://example.com/favicon.ico'>
```